# How do I inflate a RecylerView? Why do I get an RecyclerView has no LayoutManager error?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

In my task I have to make for the Recycle View it's own xml file. But now I get the error of "RecyclerView has no LayoutManager" at the point I inflate it.

Even so my task states that I have to include the Fragment part and service like this:

1. Create a single instance of the MusicStoreService in the MainActivity and provide a getter method.
2. In the ProductListFragment use (MainActivity) getActivity() to access the parent activity and from there the service.
3. Pass the service on to the ProductListAdapter's constructor

Here are the files:

Main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MusicStoreService music;
    public MainActivity() {
        super(R.layout.main);
        System.out.println("MS2021: MainActivity/"+"MainActivity".hashCode()+": MainActivity() - created");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        music = new MusicStoreServiceMock();
     
        setContentView(R.layout.product_list_fragment);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            System.out.println("MS2021: MainActivity/" + "MainActivity".hashCode() + " onCreate()");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .add(R.id.productlist_recycler, ProductListFragment.class, null)
                    .commit();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public MusicStoreService getMusic() {
        return music;
    }
```

ProductListFragement.java

```
public class ProductListFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView  recyclerView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.productlist_recycler);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        try {
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new ProductListAdapter(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getMusic()));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ProductListAdapter pld = null;
        try {
            pld = new ProductListAdapter(new MusicStoreServiceMock());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(pld);
    }
}
```

ProductListAdapter.java

```
public class ProductListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<Product> products;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView produzer;
        private TextView productName;
        private TextView priceNumber;

        public ViewHolder(View view,TextView produzer, TextView productName, TextView price) {
            super(view);
            this.produzer = produzer;
            this.productName = productName;
            this.priceNumber = price;
        }

        public TextView getProduzer() {
            return produzer;
        }

        public TextView getProductName() {
            return productName;
        }

        public TextView getPriceNumber() {
            return priceNumber;
        }

        public void setProduzer(TextView produzer) {
            this.produzer = produzer;
        }

        public void setProductName(TextView productName) {
            this.productName = productName;
        }

        public void setPriceNumber(TextView priceNumber) {
            this.priceNumber = priceNumber;
        }
    }


    public ProductListAdapter(MusicStoreService dataSet) throws FileNotFoundException {
        products = dataSet.getProducts();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout
                        .product_list_layout, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view,view.findViewById(R.id.produzer),view.findViewById(R.id.productName),view.findViewById(R.id.priceNumber));
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        format.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("EUR"));
        String price = format.format(products.get(position).getPrice().doubleValue());

        viewHolder.getProduzer().setText(products.get(position).getManufacturer());
        viewHolder.getProductName().setText(products.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.getPriceNumber().setText(price);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return products.size();
    }
}
```

product_list_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/productlist_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

product_list_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="7dp"

        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/produzer"
                android:layout_width="201dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Hoi"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hoisss"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/priceNumber"
            android:text="HoiNumber"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MusicStoreService is an interface which is implemented in MusicStoreServiceMock.

The error from Logcat:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in at.hlpinkafeld.android.musicstore:layout/product_list_fragment: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{f251fbc VFED.V... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0901ed app:id/productlist_recycler}, adapter:null, layout:null, context:at.hlpinkafeld.android.musicstore.MainActivity@c57a6e8
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{f251fbc VFED.V... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0901ed app:id/productlist_recycler}, adapter:null, layout:null, context:at.hlpinkafeld.android.musicstore.MainActivity@c57a6e8
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.generateLayoutParams(RecyclerView.java:4514)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:673)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at at.hlpinkafeld.android.musicstore.fragments.ProductListFragment.onCreateView(ProductListFragment.java:32)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1899)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1823)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1760)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2985)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2895)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:263)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:351)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:248)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1455)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8076)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3660)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

I really apperiate any help or an explaination why the way I have it now won't work.
Any help is really apperiated.

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.product_list_fragment);` – You're setting the `Activity`'s layout to the `Fragment`'s layout – which is the `<RecyclerView>` – and then trying to transact a `Fragment` into that `RecyclerView`. That's where it's throwing, when `LayoutInflater` asks the `Activity`'s `RecyclerView` for `LayoutParams` in the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()`. Do you have a separate `Activity` layout that you meant to use there? Like something with an empty `<FrameLayout>` that's meant to hold the `Fragment`? In any case, you don't want to use the `Fragment`'s.

Comment: Looking again, I think you meant for `super(R.layout.main);` in the constructor to set the layout, so you can just get rid of the `setContentView()` call. You need to make sure, though, that the `R.id` in the `.add(R.id.productlist_recycler, …)` call is the right `android:id` for some `<ViewGroup>` in the `main` layout that the `Fragment` can be placed into.

Comment: Also, you need to `return v;` instead from `ProductListFragment`'s `onCreateView()`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks a lot. I do have a layout.main that has an FragmentContainerView. I thought the RecyclerView would function the same as it. Now my App doesn't give me the error anymore. It doesn't show the correct layout though, but I can fix that. Thanks a lot again.